# Debug/Testing Facebook App Events with Segment on Expo

Tags: facebook, react-native, expo, segment

Hello community I've found finally a way to use Facebook App Events with React Native on Expo. In Expo I can use Segment and there it wraps iOS and Android sources.

On the React Native App (Expo) I tracked an event with

```
Segment.track("customEvent");
```

The Sources and Destinations are all setting up in Segment Dashboard. And after tracking that event I've got an 400 Bad Request Error in the Dashboard like that:

> This object does not exist or does not support this action

There is also an Event Tester in the Segment Dashboard. After sending a tracking event I've got following message:

> Validation Error message attribute "context.device.advertisingId" is
>   required

My question now is where should I set in? Is there an error with the IDFA? Is the App ID set up correctly? Or where is here the problem?

Comment: Hello, Did you fine a solution to this? or possibly an alternative